# Upload video in .net core 3.1 api works fine locally but doesn't work after deploy

Tags: angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Weird behavior after in .net core API I am trying to upload files (images and videos) it works just fine with images but when i try to upload video it always return error `has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` and `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED` I added this annotation
 `[HttpPost,DisableRequestSizeLimit]` and still same problem .
this is the file upload logic in frontend

```
public uploadFile(file: File): any {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    return this.http.post(`${this.environmentUrl}/api/uploads`, formData);
  }
```

Comment: files are byte streams and seems you're using different logic to upload image and video?

Comment: I added the frontend logic , i hope it helps

Comment: i think single post is not meant to upload such big files. need use some streaming methods, (tus)[https://tus.io/] is one example.